# Collision detection against complex shapes and curves

Tags: collision-detection, graphics

I am new in game development and for simple games bounding box collision is fine. However, let's say you have a shape or bitmap like this:

[image]

This is just an example but if you had more elaborate curves or even a whole shape which was more complex than a simple polygon or rectangle-like shape, how would you do precise collision detection? I am strictly speaking in 2D here. I just want to know the concept behind how you would do this.

Comment: If you need something more complex, it can always be composed by many less complex things. In your case for example many short lines .

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're representing your world as geometric primitives (points, lines, curves, polygons, etc.) rather than sprites. If you're using sprites and per-pixel collision detection, there's nothing special about odd-shaped objects. See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9954/per-pixel-based-collision-detection) for some ideas.

Using geometric primitives, the first step is to use a broad-phase algorithm to narrow down the possible pairs of objects that might intersect. See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616448/broad-phase-collision-detection-methods). Checking for collisions between each candidate pair is called the narrow phase, and you have a couple of options.

The simplest solution is to just approximate your curve using a series of line segments. If the curve is a standalone object, you'd just treat the segments as you would any other line segments in the world. If the curve is the edge of some larger object, then as a pre-processing step you'd split the larger object into smaller convex shapes using a process similar to the [trapezoid rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#mediaviewer/File:Composite_trapezoidal_rule_illustration.svg) from basic calculus. The general term for this process is "convex decomposition", and computing an optimal decomposition of arbitrary polygons is NP-complete, but a good-enough or hand-crafted decomposition will work just fine. The smaller convex subparts can be easily checked for collisions using any of a number of algorithms.

A more difficult solution is to write a custom collision algorithm for collisions between each kind of geometric primitive you want to support. Assuming you already support collisions between points, line segments, rectangles, circles, and convex polygons, adding a curve like your example would require coding a custom algorithm for the following pairs:

- Point - sine curve
- Line segment - sine curve
- Rectangle - sine curve
- Circle - sine curve
- Convex polygon - sine curve
- Sine curve - sine curve

I wouldn't recommend this approach because it's complex and ends up being a lot of work. However, if you can figure out a way to represent your objects using only convex shapes, then the [generalized GJK algorithm](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/SIGGRAPH04_Ericson_GJK_notes.pdf) will work, even if your objects have curves.

Comment: I want to know with sprites though.. what do you mean it's nothing special? How do you detect non-alpha pixels in the bitmap?

Comment: The details would depend on the pixel format used in your bitmaps, but there is a way to read the alpha channel for each pixel. Google "per-pixel collision detection sdl", replacing sdl with whatever library you're using.